# What is the android equivalent of Google Map's GMSIndoorDisplay?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I'd like to get the activeLevel, preferably from a callback along the lines of

```
- (void) didChangeActiveLevel: (GMSIndoorLevel *) level
```

from [GMSIndoorDisplayDelegate](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/reference/protocol_g_m_s_indoor_display_delegate-p). Forgive me if this is a duplicate, but in terms of an answer, I have found nothing in the docs or online about this. This is very surprising since I figured Google would have this implemented on their native android SDK if the same functionality can be found in iOS. Any help/insight will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of latest release in August 2013, google maps android api V2 **does not provide** any option for controlling finer details of indoor maps like detect if current mapview has any indoor map, detect the floor being displayed or control the floor being displayed, etc .

The only setting avaiable is to enable/disable indoor maps in a given mapview using `setIndoorEnabled()` .

Hoping that google will add the features availble in ios sdk also to android api, but I don't see any feature requests related to [adding indoormap options in android api V2](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list?can=1&q=indoor&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Stars%20ApiType%20Internal&cells=tiles)